# Python dictionary to csv excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

I try to get a csv from my dictionary in python.

I can create a csv file and put my dictionary in it.

The problem is that when I open the file with excel the header and the values are in one column, but I want all keys and all values in separate columns.

For example:

```
      column1 column2 column3        column4
row 1 "name"   "temp" "tempeinheit"  "Druck"
row 2 "test"   24      "C"             0.1
```

This is the following code.

```
dict= [{"name" : "test", "temp" : 24, "tempeinheit": "C", "druck" : 0.1,    "druckeinheit": "Pa"},{"name" : "benni", "temp" : 24, "tempeinheit": "C", "druck" : 0.1, "druckeinheit": "Pa"}]
with open("C:\\test#\\test.csv","w",newline='') as csvfile:

writer = csv.writer(csvfile,dialect="excel-tab")

for row in dict:
    if count == 0:
        header=row.keys()
        writer.writerow(header)
        count=+1
    writer.writerow(row.values())
```

Update:

I just convert the Dictionary in 2 Lists. One for the keys and one for the data, and I wrote them with the writer.writerow(Data).

The other thing is, I use excel 2013 and for a new column it's not delimiter="," but the delimiter=";". so the ";" tells excel to put the data into a new column.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: your `dict` is not dictionary, it's list of dictionaries

Comment: also, do not name your variable `dict` - you're overriding standard dictionary type

Comment: YEs i know thats a list. But even in that case i would like to save it like i described in my post

Comment: "The problem is that when i open the file with excel the header and the values are in one column" : this is primarily a problem with how excel parses your csv file - and excel can quite annoying ("braindead" comes to mind actually) when it comes to csv files. Perhaps you should try the `excel` (not 'excel-tab') dialect. Also, you should open the file in `wb` mode and probably leave the `newline` alone.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code and following problems were found.

- Import CSV error
- File was closed when you tried to write to it through the code.
- count variable was not initialized.

I haved added here my working code. Please let me know if you face any issue.

```
import csv
dict= [{"name" : "test", "temp" : 24, "tempeinheit": "C", "druck" : 0.1,    "druckeinheit": "Pa"},
    {"name" : "benni", "temp" : 24, "tempeinheit": "C", "druck" : 0}]
with open("try.csv","a") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile,dialect="excel-tab")
    count = 0
    for row in dict:
        if count == 0:
            header=row.keys()
            writer.writerow(header)
            count=+1
        writer.writerow(row.values())
```

Comment: Hi thanks but the count initialization was just a copy paste error and the file works with my c:\\try.csv. and import i forgot to post it aswell, sry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like so with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

d = [{"name" : "test", "temp" : 24, "tempeinheit": "C", "druck" : 0.1,    "druckeinheit": "Pa"},
     {"name" : "benni", "temp" : 24, "tempeinheit": "C", "druck" : 0.1, "druckeinheit": "Pa"}] 

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df = df[['name', 'temp', 'tempeinheit', 'druck','druckeinheit']]
df.to_csv('filename')
```